# Use .NET Core application in the same container as SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I wish to run an instance of SQL Server and my .NET Core application in the same docker container. All in one solution so to speak. Most solutions I see use two separate containers with compose used to orchestrate between the two.  What does the dockerfile for a single container setup look like?  And once that's done, how do I initialize the SQL instance (developer edition) and run the necessary EF update command to setup the DB tables?  Thank you.

Here is the docker file I have for my .NET Core app:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
COPY Binaries/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

And its current `appsettings.json` connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Cnxn1": "Server=(localdb);Database=ABC;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Update: Will use separate container as that's best practice. Noted a solution in the comments using SqlLite.

Comment: It’s best practice to launch a single app per container, but it is technically possible. Your would have to install both sql server and dotnet via your dockerfile. Docket only supports running 1 command, so you’d have to create a (bash) script that launches both sql server and your dotnet app. TBQH: it’s probably not worth it.

Comment: OK, I'll stick to the more traditional approach then.  I did find an article on doing this via SqlLite - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/april/data-points-ef-core-in-a-docker-containerized-app.  But I going to stick with SQL server and use separate container.

Comment: The difference with SQLite is that you don’t need to install a database server. It’s “just” a library in your code that reads a file. You should still be careful though, because that file is deleted when you remove your container

Comment: Understood.  I don't need a persistent volume.  This is not a production image, just for local dev testing hence was looking for the convenience of just a single image.